# Simplification of a combinatorial formula

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients

Can we reduce the following expression into simpler and compact form?
$$\binom{N+n}{n}-2\binom{N+n+m}{n+m+2}-\binom{N+n+m+1}{n+m+3}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a little simpler:
\begin{align}
&\binom{N+n}{n}-2\binom{N+n+m}{n+m+2}-\binom{N+n+m+1}{n+m+3}\\
&=\binom{N+n}{n}-2\binom{N+n+m}{n+m+2}-\frac{N+n+m+1}{n+m+3}\binom{N+n+m}{n+m+2} \\
&=\binom{N+n}{n}-\frac{N+3n+3m+7}{n+m+3}\binom{N+n+m}{n+m+2} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your response, I actually did reach this one. Would you say there is no way to relate the first term with second term in the last line of your expression?

Comment: You can expand into factorials and combine the fractions via a common denominator, but I would not call that simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified further to ${{N+n} \choose n} - (N+ 3(n+m) + 7)\frac{(N+n+m)!}{(N-2)!(n+m+3)!}$.